# PHPMailer Mass mailing using BCC and catching not successfull email addressses

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I am trying to send NewsLetter to 1500 users using PHPMailer and my SMTP servers.

I have tried sending the mails to 2 BCC emails for test, and it sucessfully sent mails.
But before I go ahead and send the mail to 1500 email address, I have few questions.

I am using this code snippet.

```
<?php

require "../PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php";

$bcc_list = array('emailaddrs1,emailaddress2');

$mail             = new PHPMailer();

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
$mail->Host       = "smtp.myserver.com"; // SMTP server
$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                     // enables SMTP debug information (for testing)
                                           // 1 = errors and messages
                                           // 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  // enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Host       = "smtp.myserver.com"; // sets the SMTP server
$mail->Port       = 25;                    // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
$mail->Username   = "mailer@myserver.com"; // SMTP account username
$mail->Password   = "mypasss";        // SMTP account password

$mail->SetFrom('mailer@myserver.com', 'myserver Support');

$mail->AddReplyTo("mailer@myserver.com","myserver Support");

$mail->Subject    = "Email sent from xampp";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$address = "support@myserver.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "support@myserver.com");


foreach($bcc_list as $bcc_email){
   $mail->AddBCC($bcc_email);
}

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
 //insert that emaill address into database for re-emailing.
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}
```

1) How can i make , the email show users email address in `<To>` field and not my dummy address ?

2) Does it send as 1 email or 1500 emails ? 
i.e., how can I catch which emails are successfully sent and which arent ( because of some timeout or something goes wrong) so I can send them again, and not have to spam the all others?

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's actually built into the email protocol that you can't detect which are successful.  Otherwise, this information could be used maliciously to discover email addresses for spamming purposes.

Comment: @Sildoreth i am not trying to find which hit the mailbox, i am just trying to find which i have sent successfully, in case something goes wrong , like timeout in script , big latency and/or SMTP server closes connection, or kicks me out or limits the BCC count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you are sending one message to 1 address and BCCing to all the others, so there is only a single `To` address - this is just how BCC works. If you want to have each recipient's address shown as the `To` address, you must send each message individually - look at [the mailing list example provided](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps). If you want to spot failures in a long list of recipients of any kind, make sure you're using an [up-to-date version of PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) as that was buggy in the past. Any bad addresses will be reported in `$mail->ErrorInfo`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply  , i tried putting 1500 emails in BCC but SMTP server sent SMTP ERROR: RCPT TO command failed: 452 4.5.3 Error: too many recipients message, so i did counts and they allow To + BCC total 50 email addressess at one hit. so i am using array_chunk and foreach to loop above code ....