# php mailer unsubscribe into mass email

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I use php mailer

```
require ('phpMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
```

to send mass emails. I loop my db for emails and add it to Bcc. I want to add custom unsubscribe message into each Body, but when I try something like this

```
foreach($list_mail as $db_mail) {
$unsub_email = ($db_mail[0]);
$unsubscribe1 = '<p><small>If you dont want to receive this, please click <a href="http://example.com/unsubscribe.php?email='; 
$unsubscribe2 = '">here</a></small></p>';
$email_text_unsub = $email_text . $unsubscribe1 . $unsub_email . $unsubscribe2;
$mail->Body = $email_text_unsub; }
```

I've got into each email the last listed email in URL. I understand that it will be possible if I send each email in loop (with $mail->send), but I want to send one mass email, but with customized Body.
is it possible somehow?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHPMailer Mass mailing using BCC and catching not successfull email addressses](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29001389/phpmailer-mass-mailing-using-bcc-and-catching-not-successfull-email-addressses)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have said, if you're sending a mail to multiple recipients at once, then it has to be the same email content -- that's how email works. It's not a limitation of PHP or phpMailer, it's just the way email works.

Your choices are:

1. Send a separate mail to each user. As you say, this will cause you to quickly run into rate limits with your provider. You might change provider, but everyone will have a limit of some sort or another. If you really have a need to send lots of emails, you will end up paying for it.
2. Split your mailing list so that you only send to part the list each day. That may help you keep within the rate limits, if it's a daily limit. (it won't help for monthly limits, though)
3. Use a dedicated third party email service like https://sendgrid.com/. Sendgrid *(other similar providers also exist)* provide an SMTP mail service tailored for marketing mails. Their basic service is free and allows you to send up to 400 unique mails per day. If that figure is significantly better than your own provider, they may be worth considering. (they also give you a dashboard showing stats and whether you're being flagged as spam, etc, so there is additional value in that as well)
4. Just send the same single mail to everyone, but with a generic unsubscribe link. Since everyone gets the same mail, the unsubscribe link can't include any user-specific tokens, so your users will have to enter their email address into the unsubscribe page, so a minor inconvenience for them, but it does allow you to send the via BCC per your original plan.

Comment: I did it with generic unsubscribe link and create a simple page, where user puts his email address and click unsubscribe, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to send a different mail body to each address, you cannot use BCC. You will have to send as many emails as addresses.

Comment: thats the problem because providers mail server has limitation how many emails can be sent in a day...so I have to change unsubscribe function to link where they will put their email and confirm unsubscribe
thanks

Answer (score 0):

As @aurel.g said, you *must* send individual messages for this to be possible.

BCC means that all recipients receive the same message (because only one message is submitted), so there is no opportunity to customise on a per-recipient basis.

PHPMailer provides a [mailing list sending example](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps) that shows how to do the actual send; it's up to you to design an unsubscribe mechanism to go with it.

If your host doesn't allow you to send enough, it's time to find a better host.